# Python3 - [Errno 32] Broken Pipe while using sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, broken-pipe

I have the following code for the server:

```
import socket
import threading

def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print ("[*] Received: %s" % request)
    client_socket.send("ACK!".encode("utf-8"))
    client_socket.close()

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9998
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)
print ("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port))

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print ("[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (client))
    client_handler.start()
```

And the following on the client side:

```
def client_sender(buffer):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((target, port))
    if len(buffer) > 0:
        client.send(buffer.encode("utf-8"))
        data = client.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
        print(" - " + data)
    while True:
        buffer = input("Input:")
        buffer += "\n"
        client.send(buffer.encode("utf-8"))
        data = client.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
        print (" - " + data)
```

The function client_sender is called by another function where I can choose if listen incoming connection or send data to someone.
I will call it in this way:

python3 filename.py -ip 0.0.0.0 -port 9998

I can then write some data. The first time I do it I press CTRL + D to send it and the server gets and the client gets the response.But when I try to send some data from inside the "While True" loop the server never gets it and I receive this:

```
client.send(buffer.encode("utf-8"))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**How do I solve it?** The only solution I found that works is to move these two lines inside the "While True" loop:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target, port))
```

However it seems inefficient to me to re-connect every time.

**EDIT**
As suggested by Sam Mason, changing the handle_client in the following way solves the problem:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if len(request):
            print ("[*] Received: %s" % request)
            client_socket.send("ACK!".encode("utf-8"))
        else:
            client_socket.close()
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your server is closing the port immediately after a single `recv`.  I'd suggest changing your `handle_client` code to have some sort of `while` loop that ends when `recv` returns an empty string (this indicates the client has `shutdown` their end of the connection, probably by `close`ing their connection)